# MySQL foreign key 1215

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I'm coming from an Oracle background and am setting up a quick project using a MySQL database.  I'm running into issues adding a simple foreign key constraint.  Could someone please help me with my syntax?

```
/************************************************************/
/*tables/schema*/
/*Familes*/
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Familes(
fID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
signature blob DEFAULT NULL,
signatureTS TIMESTAMP,
createdTS TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
) ENGINE=INNODB;

/*familyMembers*/
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FamilyMembers(
fmID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
fName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
lName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
age INTEGER NOT NULL,
sex BIT(1) NOT NULL, /*0 indicates male, 1 indicates female*/
ssNum VARCHAR(9) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
recievedBig BIT(1) DEFAULT 0,
recievedNormal BIT(1) DEFAULT 0,
recievedStocking BIT(1) DEFAULT 0,
famID INTEGER,
INDEX fIndex (famID), /*index for optimization on searching*/
FOREIGN KEY (famID) REFERENCES Families(fID)  
    ON DELETE CASCADE 
    /*foreign key constraint, not deferred b/c family should always exist first*/
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

I can create the first table just fine.  I can also create the second when I comment out the fk.  However, when I leave the fk constraint in, I get the follwoing error:

> Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

This should be a quick fix.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have misspelt the first table name.  I think you intend `Families` rather than `Familes`.

Comment: perfect! thank you.